# Kinetic/Canvas drag and drop image on another image and save it

Tags: html, image, canvas, drag-and-drop

hey i´d like to drag and drop (also resize) a smaller image over a bigger/background image to the position i want and finally save it to a new image. This should be possible with canvas but i can´t figure it out how to do it properly.

I already found [that for resizing and drag and drop it](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/):

Now i need to put the bigger image in the background and finally save everything to a new image.

I found [this for saving it](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-stage-data-url-with-kineticjs/), but can´t connect the puzzles...

Another problem is, that i want to do it for mobile devices, so i need to set the background image in percentage value(100%,100%) to fit in the display of the device.
Can´t figure it out. pls help

Comment: So what have you coded up thus far?

Comment: well, nothing.. i tried to combine the codes but it didn´t work..